# Zip File from S3 files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, zip

Ruby '2.7.4'

Rails '~> 5.2.2'

I have access to an S3 bucket containing several files of several types, which I am trying to

1. Download into memory
2. Put them all together inside a zip file
3. Upload this zip file into some S3 bucket

I've looked into several issues on the web already, without any success.
Specifically, I'm trying to use the `rubyzip` gem, but no matter what I do, I always end up with the error message : 'no implicit conversion of StringIO into String'

Here's a summary of my current code

```
gem 'rubyzip', require: 'zip'
require 'zip'

bucket_name = 'redacted'
zip_filename = "My final complete zip file.zip"
s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'eu-west-3')
s3_resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'eu-west-3')
bucket = s3_resource.bucket(bucket_name)
s3_filename = 's3_file_name'
s3_file = s3_client.get_object(bucket: bucket_name, key: s3_filename)
file = s3_file.body
```

At this point, I have exactly **one** file, in a StringIO format.
**However please bear in mind that I'm trying to reproduce this with several files, which means I want to bundle several files inside a final zip.**
I'm failing to put this file into a zip and/or put the zip back into s3.

**Attempt N°1**

```
stringio = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zio|
  zio.put_next_entry("test1.zip")
  zio.write(file)
end

stringio.rewind
binary_data = stringio.sysread
```

**Error message :** `no implicit conversion of StringIO into String`

**Attempt N°2**

```
zip_file_name = 'my_test_file_name.zip'
File.open(zip_file_name, 'w') { |f| f.puts(file.rewind && file.read) }

final_zip = Zip::File.open(zip_filename, create: true) do |zipfile|
  zf = Zip::File.new(file, create: true, buffer: true)
  zipfile.add(zf.to_s, zip_file_name)
end

really_final_zip = Zip::File.new(final_zip, create: true, buffer: true)

new_object = bucket.object(zip_file_name)
new_object.put(body: final_zip)
```

**Error Message :** `expected params[:body] to be a String or IO like object that supports read and rewind, got value #<Zip::Entry:0x0000558a06ff42a0`
If instead of that last line, I write
`new_object.put(body: final_zip.to_s)`
A text file is created in S3 (instead of the zip) with the content `#<StringIO:0x0000558a06c8c8d8>`

Comment: change `s3_file.body` to `s3_file.body.read`

Comment: IT WORKED ! I have modified my code with `zio.write(file.read)` and I'm able to make it work.
Can you make it an answer and I will mark it as the correct one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to read the bytes from the file so...

change
`s3_file.body` to `s3_file.body.read`